# ¿ Cómo configurar la consola de desarrollador de JavaScript de Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-developers-console

Hola he visto en varios ejemplo la posibilidad de cuando hacemos un console.log repetitivo, que la consola imprime una vez el mensaje y un número con las veces que repetimos ese evento  [como en el ejemplo que se repitió el evento en 28](http://prntscr.com/j4nf29)   ocasiones. 
Bien, a mi me imprime directamentamente en mensaje en cuestión todas las veces que realice el evento como muestro en la imagen de la parte de abajo.
Di vueltas por Google, los foros de google y las herramientas de Chrome sin éxito.
¿ Donde encuentro esa configuración para que me muestre el numero al repetir `console.log` en vez de imprimir el mensaje en cuestión una y otra vez; o tiene que ver con la versión de Chrome ?. La mía es: *Versión 65.0.3325.181 (Build oficial) (64 bits)*
Muestro las capturas por si mis explicaciones no son elocuentes.
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consola sólo agrupa los mensajes idénticos. En el ejemplo que pones en la imagen no son idénticos aunque los llame siempre un mismo evento. De todas formas, veo que estás imprimiendo el `Timestamp` por lo que, aunque el mensaje fuera idéntico, nunca te los agruparía.

Para evitar esto tienes que ir a la configuración y desmarcar "Show timestamps"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un ejemplo con la opción marcada y sin marcar:

**Con Timestamps**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Sin Timestamps**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edito**:

Una opción interesante que te podría servir es utilizar las funciones [group()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group) y [groupCollapsed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/groupCollapsed) del objeto `console`. Con ellas puedes agrupar lo que quieras y ponerles tu propio label. Te dejo un ejemplo [aquí](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ev85gbz8/)

> Nota: Ten en cuenta que hay que cerrar el grupo con `groupEnd` porque si 
>   no te hará grupos dentro de grupos.

Comment: Gracias @Kiko_L solucionado con  desmarcar "Show timestamps" .